Issues with IK rigging a robotic arm (Inverse Kinematics with rotation limits and pole target)
Trying to IK rig this robot and running into issues. How it should look with FK posing:

The robotic arm does not have a ball joint in the shoulder but a rotational joint plus a hinge. Similar to the elbow, these joints can only rotate around one axis and the degree of rotation is limited.
The shoulder IK problem
I initially didn't have the green bones and only had the yellow ones, a normal IK bone chain (see screenshot below). I've locked and limited the rotation for the bones in the IK Bone Panel. When adding the IK constraint to the forearm, it caused issues with rotating the IKBicep_shoulder_connector_bone when the Pole Target was set.
Workaround tried
I was given some advice to use the green bones as a sort of proxy to mimic the movement of a typical IK rigged arm so the pole target would work on the elbow. I was trying to use copy rotation constraints to copy the green bones rotation onto the yellow bones.
The connection between the arm and the shoulder is two bones, which makes IK rigging more troublesome. I've tried adding a two-bone "real" IK chain that mirrors a typical arm IK chain that the IK deform bones can copy constraints from. The bones in green are the "real" IK bones and the yellow are the IK bones for the deform bones.

After playing with the constraints on the yellow bones the forearm disconnects from the bicep:

Another issue is that due to how each arm bone rotates on a single axis, movements like this break the connection:

Edit:
Tried adding more "puppet" bones as well as one for the forearm. Using limit rotation constraints to mimic IK locks. The IKBicep_bone_l still doesn't rotate correctly



Sorry, I have to ask a few questions because I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why is there a green bicep bone and additionally 2 yellow bones? Why do the yellow bones have a copy rotation constraint that copies the Y-bone rotation of the IK arm control ("hand IK")? This makes no sense to me. Why do you expect that the yellow bones follow the green bicep bone? They are not in the bone chain so they won't move.

I initially didn't have the green bones and only had the yellow ones. When adding the IK constraint to the forearm, it would cause issues with rotating the IKBicep_shoulder_connector_bone when the Pole Target was set. I was given some advice to use the green bones as a sort of proxy to mimic the movement of a typical IK rigged arm so the pole target would work on the elbow. I was trying to use copy rotation constraints to copy the green bones rotation onto the yellow bones. Is there a more efficient way to IK rig this arm?

Ah, thanks for the explanation. Now I see the problem. It's the IK limits+the pole target. I've edited your question & added the details. The problem is very old. There are similar questions (https://blenderartists.org/t/pole-target-and-ik-limits-problem/546861) & a bug report from 2011 (https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/28313). Have you found this one? https://devtalk.blender.org/t/pole-target-and-inverse-kinematics-limits/5604? Your workaround seems to be similar to the "puppet" copy mentioned in the last comment, just with additional bones instead of a copy of the armature

Without the pole it works: https://i.sstatic.net/pB7gRrGf.jpg - By the way, I think the bicep_shoulder and bicep_connector bones are not aligned properly to the model. I've moved their head/tails to the center of the joints and connected them because the shoulder bolt thing was pushed into the body. Also, one of the arm meshes has duplicated vertices and the scale is not applied to model.

Thanks for the additional info. Reading the last comment on the devtalk, instead of only have two green bones, I should match the number of green bones to yellow bones and copy transform onto the yellow bones, correct?

If I understand the comment correctly, the entire armature is copied. Just like you do with animation retargeting. The “puppet master” armature has the IK and the “puppet” has the constraints. But I'm not sure if this is right. I've never done this before and don't know exactly how it should or can work. It's also a massive overhead. There is another comment (the first one), where they suggest to use 2 IK chains. But it seemed not to work in Blender 2.8.

I see, is there another way I should go around this? With constraints and "puppet" bones it's half-way there, but certain poses would be impossible compared to FK posing.
